# How to properly set checkbox checked attribute from reactive data source on render

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have multiple checkboxes whose checked attributes represent boolean values in a collection. My code properly tracks the click event on the checkboxes and updates the values in the collection. However, when the page first loads, and when the user navigates away from the page, the checked attribute does not get set properly, despite the session and collection values being correct.

The html

```
<input type="checkbox" id="feedEmailSubscribe" checked={{isChecked}}>
```

Helper JS

```
Template.layout.isChecked = function () {
  var id = $this.id;
  return Session.get(id) ? "checked" : "";
};
```

I first pull down the collection and set a session variable for the checkbox via an 'invites' route

```
// invites
  this.route('invites', {
    path: ':_id/invited-guest/VIP',
    waitOn : function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('guests', this.params._id);
    },
    data: function () {
      Session.set('guestId', this.params._id)
      return Guests.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
    },
    action : function () {
      var q = Guests.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
      if (this.ready()) {
        Session.set('guestName', q.name);
        Session.set('feedEmailSubscribe', q.feedEmailSubscribe);
        //...I then redirect the user
      }
    },
  });
```

I can verify the Sessions get set. Here is what I have for the settings route (where the checkbox exists)

```
// settings page
  this.route('settings', {
    path: '/settings',
    waitOn : function () {
      return Meteor.subscribe('guests', Session.get('guestId'));
    },
    data: function () {
      return Guests.findOne({_id: Session.get('guestId')});
    },
    action: function () {
    if (this.ready())
        this.render();
    },
    onAfterAction: function() {
      setPageTitle('Settings');
    }
  });
```

I can verify the Session exists and that it properly changes once clicked after page render. I suspect I'm either not using Blaze correctly as briefly discussed in the [Blaze wiki](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected), or I've got something wrong in my iron-router setup?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 4):

In the helper, your line

```
  return Session.get(id) ? "checked" : "";
```

should be changed to

```
  return Session.get(id) ? "checked" : false;
```

This is because the empty string generates the empty html attribute `checked=""`. An empty boolean attribute [represents a true value according to HTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attribute). You have to omit the attribute in order to have a false value, this can be achieved by returning `false`, `null` or `undefined`, according to the Meteor documentation as Bozhao referred.

Don't be surprised because the resulting code doesn't show up as an attribute. Blaze uses the `element.checked` JavaScript  attribute and not the `checked` HTML attribute to actually set the checkedness. The HTML attribute [only specifies the default value](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#attr-input-checked), and has no meaning once [the user](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#concept-input-checked-dirty) or [a JS code](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-input-checked) has changed the checkedness. Blaze  [treats such specially](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ui/attrs.js#L260-L267)  the `input value`, `input checked`, `textarea value` and `option selected` attributes.

Comment: Really appreciate the explanation...very helpful. Looks like I created a possible second issue from placing my helper in the parent layout template. Moving the helper to the nested settings template works when the id is hard-coded (e.g. return Session.get('emailFeedSubscribe') ? "checked" : false;). However, even when I fix a third issue (`var id = $this.id` should be `var id = this.id` of course), the id is still coming up undefined and hence, the checkboxes remain unchecked upon render. Thanks for sending me in the right direction...getting close!

Answer (score 2):

Found a potential solution: Upon render, I loop though all the checkboxes and apply "checked" according to how the corresponding session variable is set. Doesn't feel all that elegant though.

settings.js

```
Template.settings.rendered = function () {
  $(":checkbox").each(function(){
    console.log(this.id);
    if (Session.get(this.id, true)) {
      $(this).prop("checked", true);
    }
   });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your helpers looks ok to me, however, I would return false as they documented here:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Using-Blaze#conditional-attributes-with-no-value-eg-checked-selected

Comment: Thanks. In theory, if the helper is working properly, shouldn't I be able to change the Session variable in the console and the checkbox would change? I can set the variable to false in the console and nothing happens in the html. I also noticed that even when checked, the html doesn't show "checked". Hrm....